# Multi column accordion background sliding

Tags: html, css, grid, accordion

I've been stuck on this for ages now. I'm building a FAQ section which, on desktop, has to have 2 columns on which it fills it's FAQ items. The items have a dropshadow and the whole is made with Bootstrap 4.

I've tried Flexbox, CSS columns. Now i've tried CSS Grid, however i still have the problem that whenever i open an accordion the item on the other side also expands it's body. I included a pen to demonstrate this.

**Update:** Forgot an important detail. It's a Wordpress website, with the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin i created a repeater field. Which outputs the FAQ items as an array. Therefore the amount of items is always dynamic. They need to fill out 2 columns, unless there is only 1 item ofcourse.

The html is:

```
<ul id="faq-accordion" class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="card-faq" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
    <h3>
      <button class="btn btn-link">Accordion 1</button>
    </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="collapse multi-collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#faq-accordion">
      <div class="card-body">contents
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My SCSS:

```
#faq-accordion{
  padding: 40px 30px 60px 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  .card-faq{
    margin: 0 15px 20px 15px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  }
```

The codepen: https://codepen.io/LemonNick/pen/NEjJPQ

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated! Been stuck on this for too long now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the only problem is, that the shadow is expanding, just wrap the contents of `.card-faq` in another `div` and move the shadow to there

```css
#faq-accordion {
  padding: 40px 30px 60px 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
}

.card-faq {
  margin: 0 15px 20px 15px;
}

.shadow {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<ul id="faq-accordion" class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="card-faq" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
    <div class="shadow">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
        <h3>
          <button class="btn btn-link">Accordion 1</button>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="collapse multi-collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#faq-accordion">
        <div class="card-body">contents
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card-faq" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
    <div class="shadow">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
        <h3>
          <button class="btn btn-link">Accordion 1</button>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="collapse multi-collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#faq-accordion">
        <div class="card-body">contents
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

working in you codepen like so : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gQWywr?editors=0100

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Do you by any chance know how to stop the other column from expanding when an item get's expanded?

Comment: no sorry i don't have experience with css grid and how children behave in them

Answer (score 1):

Second isn't expanding it's body. But rather li is following height as it's in grid. You just need to replace shadow from li element to card-body. So from this one 
`#faq-accordion .card-faq` 
. I just checked body stays collapsed. But shadow from li element is making illusion.
Btw I have adjusted your pen

Comment: Thank you sir! that did the trick :) Do you also happen to know if it's possible to make the the other side immovable? That the white space on the other side doesn't increase when an item is expanded?

Comment: It's possible only if you put ul element inside div and then set li elements as float:left or display:inline-block. then it will stay immovable. 
So you would have row element and inside it just div and inside div ul element

Comment: I updated my pen with your suggested code, i can't get it to work though. Could you help me out if it isn't too much trouble? (https://codepen.io/LemonNick/pen/NEjJPQ)

Comment: Ok let me check it

Comment: @Amst3l check now I have fixed it

Comment: Ok great. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider using a couple of divs with a float on them:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .faq {
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="faq"><!--Put your first column cards here--></div>
    <div class="faq"><!--Put your second column cards here--></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention the items itself is loaded through an array. The website is build for Wordpress, the items itself is a repeater field from the ACF plugin. I shall update my original question!

Comment: This should still work. Just load the items in with JS